# Is there a non-zero entire function $|f(z)|^2 \leq |\cos z|$ for all z?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

could you give me a hint on how to approach problems like this:

Prove or disprove the existence of non-zero entire function such that

$$ |f(z)|^2 \leq|\cos z|$$ for all $z$ in $C$.

I think this one is similar too:

Let $f$ is a meromorphic function and $|f(z)|^3 \leq |\tan z|$ for all $z$ in $C \setminus\{P(f)\}$, where P(f) is a set of poles of $f$ in $C$. Prove that $f  \equiv0$.
The only thing I see doing is assuming that there is not such a function and then trying to apply Liouville theorem for an entire function $g(z)=1/(f(x)$, but it doesn't help. 
Thank you.

Comment: what if $z=\pi/2$

Comment: I suppose that your inequality is in fact with $\leq$. Put $g(z)=\frac{f(z)^2}{\cos(z)}$. Show that $g$ is entire, and bounded. Apply Liouville, and have a look at the multiplicity of the zeros of $\cos(z)$.

Comment: Yes, it is $\leq$ there, thank you for correcting @Kelenner . I can see the part where $f(z)^2=c \cos z, |c|<1$, and $f(z) =0$ if $z= +-\pi/2 +2\pi k$. I can't apply identity theorem, how do I show $f=0$ for all $z$?

Comment: As @Kelenner said, look at the order of the zero of $f^2$ and $\cos z$ at $\pi/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(z) = f(z)^3 \cos z$ in your second question. $g$ is meromorphic and less than $\sin z$ in magnitude where it's defined.